# Spark streaming job exited with code 11

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am using spark streaming job to execute multiple tasks. It is running fine for around 5-6 hours but after that it failed with following exception. Spark streaming job is running on yarn cluster with 20 GB RAM and 8 core.

```
Application application_1435667829099_0003 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1435667829099_0003_000002 exited with exitCode: 11
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://hdp-master:8088/proxy/application_1435667829099_0003/Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_e09_1435667829099_0003_02_000001
Exit code: 11
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=11:
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:538)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:715)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:212)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 11
Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
```

Please suggest me.

Comment: Can you share the code related to the error?

Comment: Sorry, as code is too long, I can't share the code. I can give you snippet. I have multiple window functions with different time range and delay. All window functions are in same spark context and reading from same kafka topic.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was line before exception in node-manager's log:

```
INFO org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster: Final app status: FAILED,
exitCode: 11, (reason: Max number of executor failures (16) reached)
```

But I'm sure it's drawback of original issue. Take a look closely on node-manager logs

Comment: I am getting the same line in logs before exception too. How did you solve this problem? What is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that the solution I found can resolve your issue or not. However, it resolved my issue related to `exitCode: 11 (reason: Max number of executor failures (16) reached)`

The root cause of my issue is we use sparkContext.stop() at the end of main function. It stops all executors. However, some async process (akka tries to send message) still works and try to call driver/executors. It cannot call successfully because all executors/driver has been shut down. It tries many times and stop with exitCode: 11.

Solution: remove sparkContext.stop() function on your code, leave the stop action for GC.